# Python selenium gives me an empty string for <span> text<span>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an HTML page that contains 40 of the following div

```
<div class='movie-featured'>
    <div class="item analytics">
        <div class="movie-details">
            <div class="movie-rating-wrapper">
                <span class="movie-rating-summary">
                    <span>some text</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to get the text from this span `<span>some text</span>` rom inside each one of the 40 divs via: `find_element_by_css_selector('span.moview-rating-summary').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text`

Output:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '6/10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '7.5/10', '', '', '', '', '']
```

As you can see, I only get text from few spans and not all of them.

I also tried: `find_element_by_tag_name('span').get_attribute('textContent')` and `find_element_by_tag_name('span').get_attribute('innerHTML')`.

But still the same result

Any ideas how to fix that??

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
delay = 10 
browser.get("www.example.com")


browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
time.sleep(2)
images =[]

myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'item-responsive')))


body = browser.find_element_by_class_name('movie-featured') # body of images container

imageItems = body.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.item.analytics')  #list of divs that hold movies images


for item in imageItems:
    
    rate = item.find_element_by_css_selector('span.moview-rating-summary').text

    images.append(rate)
    
print(images)
browser.close()
```

Thank you guys for all the help you gave.
I fixed the problem by changing my code as follows:

```
body = browser.find_element_by_class_name('movie-featured')
rateDivs = body.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="moview-rating-wrapper"]')
ratelist = []
for div in rateDivs:
    span = div.find_element_by_css_selector('span.moview-rating-summary')
    ratespan = span.find_element_by_tag_name('span')
    rate = ratespan.text
    if len(rate) > 0:
        ratelist.append(rate)
    else:
        continue
print(ratelist)

browser.close()
```

I really appreciate all the time you spent to help me.

Comment: Good first question! Keep posting!

Comment: Can you share the url you're using?  - I think there's a more efficient way using find_elements_ to just get what you want without the loop but if like to test it before I post an answer

Comment: @RichEdwards the url i'm using is private to my ISP in my country and It won't work outside the country

Comment: It feels like there's something in your identifiers that's not working as expected.  Do you know how to use devtools to review all matches?

Comment: @RichEdwards No, unfortunately I don't know how review them.

Comment: Open devtools (F12), go to the element tab, press crtl+f, and enter your xpath or css.  Everything your identifier matches is what you'll return with find_elements - review those and ensure they all have text as you expect... The xpath by legend42 is pretty much what I would use so put that in and see if all the spans have text.... If you're certain your spans have text then consider if they all need to be scrolled into view to "exist".

Answer (score 1):

To extract the texts e.g. *some text*, from allof the `<span>` using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.movie-rating-summary>span")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='movie-rating-summary']/span")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="movie-rating-summary"]/span[1]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your way and I got the same output in the post [empty strings]. is there a way to check if an element <span> has data??

Comment: You can cross check by executing the below code in Chrome Developer toll console.`var doc = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName");for(var i=0; i<doc.length; i++){console.log(doc.item(i).innerText)};`

Comment: @DilipMeghwal it gave me all the values form the span elements, but I still can't get them in my selenium code.

Comment: what is the xpath for <div class="movie-rating-wrapper"> counting from <div class='movie-featured'>??

Comment: @MartinWittick Can you use `item.find_element_by_css_selector('span.moview-rating-summary').get_attribute("innerText")` while capturing rate.

Comment: @MartinWittick you can use a simple if statement to check for data:
`if element!='':`